# Unable to access the application with container IP address in Windows 10

Tags: docker

I am running an application on docker container in my Windows10. I have mapped container port with localhost port. Application is accessble with localhost:port but unable to access the application with container IPaddress:port. And not able to signin/signup to the application(even with localhost:port) which is running in docker container within client VPN from Windows10 host.

Comment: It sounds like you have the essence of it: the container-internal IP address really isn't useful and there's not much point in looking it up.  What application is it specifically, and what error are you getting trying to access it?

Comment: Thank you for helping out. This is an application (portal) having authenticated and non-authenticated scenarios. For authenticated scenarios the application does backend SAML calls which works only when the server hosting the application is on VPN.  I have moved this application to a container which is running on my windows10 laptop. I first logged onto VPN and then started Docker desktop for Windows and then brought up the container. The application loads and is accessible over localhost and the Docker NAT IP. However authentication fails by giving a blank page. Kindly suggest your views.